# Rotate Doubly Linked List

Tags: c#, list, linked-list, big-o, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to rotate a doubly linked list both clockwise and counter clockwise. However my code only outputting a part of the list. I understand that the list should not rotate if there are 0 or 1 elements. I would like to rotate to the right if the value is greater than 1. Also, I would like to rotate to the left if the value is less than 0. I'm not sure what I have done wrong with my list. The logic is very confusing. The addLast method has intentionally not been included since it works.

```
public class Node
    {
        public Node next;
        public Node previous;
        public Object data;

    }
public class LinkedList
    {
        private Node head;
        private Node tail;
        public Node rotate(int k)
        {
            if (head == null )
            {
                return head;
            }
            Node node = head;

            k = k % listSize(head);
           
            if (k == 0 || k == 1)
            { 
                return head;
            }
             //Rotates
            while (node != null && k > 1)
            {
                node = node.next;
                k--;
            }

            Node newhead = node.next;
            newhead.previous = null;
            node.next = null;
            Node temp = newhead;
            while (temp.next != null)
            {
                temp = temp.next;
            }

            newhead = head;
            node.previous = temp.previous;
            tail = node;

            return newhead;
        }

        public int listSize(Node node)
        {
            if(node == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            int count = 0;
            while(node != null)
            {
                count++;
                node = node.next;
            }
            return count;

        }

        public void addLast(Object data)
        {
            Node toAdd = new Node();
            toAdd.data = data;
            toAdd.next = null;
            if (head == null)
            {
                head = toAdd;
                tail = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (tail == null)
                {
                    head.next = toAdd;
                    tail = toAdd;
                }
                else
                {
                    tail.next = toAdd;
                    tail = toAdd;
                }
            }
        }
}
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add Last: ");
            LinkedList myList2 = new LinkedList();

            myList2.addLast("Tim");
            myList2.addLast("Nick");
            myList2.addLast("Julie");
            myList2.addLast("Jessie");
            myList2.addLast("Jordan");
            myList2.addLast("Peter");
            myList2.addLast("John");
             myList2.rotate(2);
}
```

Edit: I have tried rewriting my code before reading any comments. It still does rotate the list successfully.

Comment: Sit down with a piece of paper and pencil and see what your code is doing.

Comment: I'm guessing you want the result of rotate(2) to be "Julie" .. "John" then "Tim", "Nick"?  What's the actual result?    I've found that walking through the code, even on paper, can help with linked data structures.  Draw diagrams if needed.  Are you going one step to far with  Node newhead = node.next;?  (Posting the code that works too will allow other people to run what you have: a  minimal, reproducible example)

Comment: @toastifer I have already tried writing it out however it still does not work. However, I noticed a few unnecessary issues with my code that have been fixed in my question.

Comment: @toastifer Each time I try to rewrite my code it starts an infinite loop or only prints out a part of the code. I've tried placing breakpoints in the program however after I change my code it still does not work. Also, I've tried drawing it out. After I try changing my code it still does not work. I have also tried explaining the process by writing comments next to each line of code however I still receive infinite loops or sections of the code are only printed out.

Comment: Be careful when setting the `Next` property of one node to another - don't forget to then also set the `Previous` property of the other node to the first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's tough, and I had many of the same problems.  One thing that helped was renaming some of the variables to make it clear in my head what was going on.

In the rotate function:

```
        public Node rotate(int k)
        {
            if (head == null)
            {
                return head;
            }

            k = -k;  
            k = k % listSize(head);
            if (k<0) { k+= listSize(head); }

            if (k == 0 )
            {
                return head;
            }
            //Rotates
            Node newhead = head;

            while (newhead != null && k > 0)
            {
                newhead = newhead.next;
                k--;
            }
            Node newtail = newhead.previous;
            
            newhead.previous = null;
            newtail.next = null;

            tail.next = head;
            head.previous = tail;
                

            head = newhead;
            tail = newtail;

            return newhead;
        }
```

(This assumes you're keeping the tail updated in addLast().  If you are, you may as well use it.  Here's what I had:)

```
    public void addLast(Object inData)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.next = null;
        node.data = inData;
        node.previous = tail;
        if (head == null) 
        { 
            head = node; 
        }
        if (tail != null)
        {
            tail.next = node;
        }
        tail = node;
    }
```

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: I am getting an error at the line New newtail = newhead.previous because newhead.previous is null. Also this appears to rotate to the left if k is positive. I am trying to rotate to the left using a negative number and to the right using a positive number.

Comment: It looks like you're not setting previous in the addLast method, and that's essential for a doubly linked list.  I'll update my answer with my version.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I think you're missing is that anytime you set one nodes `Next` property, you should also set the corresponding next node's `Previous` property. Just doing that may help with the list navigation.

Otherwise, it can be helpful to break down the tasks into more discreet methods, so there's not too much going on in one method.

One thing that may be helpful, for example, is to add a method that returns a node at a specific index. This allows us to easily grab a node and set it to the new `Head`, which means our `Rotate` method doesn't need a loop - it just gets the node at the appropriate index and sets that node as the new head.

Note that setting a node as a new Head node should also be broken out into a new method, since there's a fair amount involved there as well (a new head means a new tail, and lots of `Previous` and `Next` properties to think about).

Hopefully this implementation based on your code is instructive. Please let me know if something doesn't make sense:

```
public class Node
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }
    public Node Previous { get; set; }

    public Node(object data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Data.ToString();
    }
}

public class LinkedList 
{
    public Node Head { get; private set; }
    public Node Tail { get; private set; }
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            var count = 0;
            for (var n = Head; n != null; n = n.Next, count++) ;
            return count;
        }
    }

    private void AddFirst(object data)
    {
        var node = new Node(data) {Next = Head?.Next};
        if (Head != null) { Head.Previous = node;}
        if (Tail == null) Tail = node;
        Head = node;
    }

    public void Add(object data)
    {
        if (Head == null)
        {
            AddFirst(data);
        }
        else
        {
            var node = new Node(data) {Previous = Tail?.Previous};
            if (Tail != null) Tail.Next = node;
            node.Previous = Tail;
            Tail = node;
        }
    }

    private Node ItemAt(int index)
    {
        var item = Head;
        while (index-- > 0) item = item.Next;
        return item;
    }

    private void SetNewHead(int indexOfNewHead)
    {
        var newHead = ItemAt(indexOfNewHead);
        var newTail = newHead.Previous;
        var oldHead = Head;
        var oldTail = Tail;

        newHead.Previous = null;
        newTail.Next = null;
        oldTail.Next = oldHead;
        oldHead.Previous = oldTail;

        Head = newHead;
        Tail = newTail;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rotates the Tail to the Head the specified number of times
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rotations">
    /// The number of times to rotate the Tail to the Head
    /// A negative number rotates the Head to the Tail
    /// </param>
    public void Rotate(int rotations)
    {
        var count = Count;
        rotations = rotations % count;
        if (rotations == 0) return;

        // Find the index of the new head based on the number of rotations
        // If rotations is positive, then the index is the count minus rotations
        // If rotations is negative, then the index is 'rotations * -1' (or -rotations) 
        var newHeadIndex = rotations > 0 ? count - rotations : -rotations;

        // Now that we know the index of the new head, we just set it as the head
        SetNewHead(newHeadIndex);
    }

    public List<Node> ToList()
    {
        var nodes = new List<Node>();
        for (var node = Head; node != null; node = node.Next)
        {
            nodes.Add(node);
        }
        return nodes;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Count == 0 ? "{no items}" : "'" + string.Join("' <-> '", ToList()) + "'";
    }
}
```

And here's a sample program that lets you enter some data and then rotate the list:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var linkedList = new LinkedList();

    while (true)
    {
        var data = GetStringFromUser("Enter data to add, or 'exit' to stop: ");
        if (data.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            break;
        linkedList.Add(new Node(data));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nLinked list items:");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine(linkedList);
    Console.ResetColor();

    while (true)
    {
        var rotations = GetIntFromUser("\nEnter number of rotations, or 42 to stop: ");
        if (rotations == 42) break;
        linkedList.Rotate(rotations);
        Console.WriteLine($"\nLinked list items after {rotations} rotations:");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(linkedList);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

The code above uses the following helper methods:

```
public static string GetStringFromUser(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return Console.ReadLine();
}

public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<double, bool> validator = null)
{
    bool isValid = true;
    int result;

    do
    {
        if (!isValid)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please try again.");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        else isValid = false;

        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) &&
                (validator == null || !validator.Invoke(result)));

    return result;
}
```

**Sample Output**

[image]